# How can I rewrite login users to be lowercase?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, ldap

The larger problem is that LDAP authentication in Windows is case-insensitive but the program(s) using this feature for authentication **are** case sensitive. Two such programs are Collabnet SubversionEdge and Adobe Version Cue.  Any variation on the case of the user name results in another user entry in those packages. And this user will have no access, frustrating the person, and clogging the help desk with tickets.

Collabnet Subversion Edge uses Apache 2.2 so I intend to intercept the url and rewrite the username to enforced lowercase at the server-side.

example input:

```
https://User:password@svn.domain.com
https://USER@svn.domain.com
svn://useR:password@svn.domain.com/Repo/Trunk/BIN/
svn://svn.domain.com/Repo/Trunk/BIN/
```

desired rewrite:

```
https://user:password@svn.domain.com
https://user@svn.domain.com
svn://user:password@svn.domain.com/Repo/Trunk/BIN/
svn://svn.domain.com/Repo/Trunk/BIN/
```

Notice that the rest of the url is unchanged.

*Bonus question:* 
Will this ReWriteRule handle all cases for Collabnet Edge?

The other ways to talk to the server are:

1) Through the browser-based management console:

```
<form action='/csvn/j_spring_security_check' method='POST' id='loginForm'>
 <input type='text' class='text_' name='j_username' id='j_username' value='' />
 <input type='password' class='text_' name='j_password' id='j_password' />
 <input type='submit' value='Login' class="Button"/>
</form>
```

2) svn clients

eg. TortoiseSVN, AnhkSVN, and subserversion client via the commandline.

Comment: I ended up not using the LDAP feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piece of cake (hear irony here?): please checkout how RewriteMap can use internal functions (see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap)), here it's the `tolower` function:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteMap  lc int:tolower
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ([a-zA-Z0-9]+):([a-zA-Z0-9]+)@svn.domain.com(.*) [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} svn.domain.com/(.+)
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [R=301,L]
```

This should work.
I hope I've given you enough clues to finish the job ;)
If you don't have enough clues...

### Two hints:

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Sounds like a great place to start. These rules go in .htaccess? or httpd.conf?

Comment: Everything is broken now. Need to restore and start over.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question but I came up with this problem related also to 
Apache, Subversion and LDAP/Active Directory and I believe the workaround may be helpful.

To transform the login to lowercase, it suffices to rewrite the "Authorization" HTTP request header where user credentials are encoded. With basic authentication this header has the format (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication):

```
Authorization: Basic <base64_usr_pwd>
```

Where <base64_usr_pwd> is the Base64-encoding of the string <login>+":"+<password>.

To rewrite this header we used a mod_perl module that handles the "header parser" phase that takes place prior to the authentication, as described in: https://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/handlers/intro.html#mod_perl_Handlers_Categories.

We put the following mod_perl directive in the <Location> section of our SVN repository in the Apache configuration files:

```
PerlHeaderParserHandler MyApache2::ConvertUsrToLowercase
```

The Perl module simply reads the login and password, transforms the former to lowercase, rewrites the "Authorization" HTTP request header with the transformed login and returns OK:

```
    package MyApache2::ConvertUsrToLowercase;

    use strict;
    use APR::Base64;
    use Apache2::RequestRec;
    use Apache2::Const -compile => qw(OK DECLINED);

    sub handler {
        my $request = shift;
        my ($res, $passwd) = $request->get_basic_auth_pw;        # get passwd
        my $user = lc $request->user;                            # get lowercase login
        my $auth_header = APR::Base64::encode("$user:$passwd");
        # rewrite header & return OK
        $request->headers_in->{'Authorization'} = "Basic $auth_header";
        return Apache2::Const::OK;
    }


    1;
```

Answer (score 0):

LDAP is not "case-insensitive". Comparisons of attributes and entries performed by the directory server are performed using [matching rules](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/11/22/matching-rules-comparisons/), which is entirely different from case-insensitivity. Failure to use matching rules to perform comparisons will lead to unexpected results.

Comment: That's why i want to alter the case before it reaches the LDAP authentication query. I want to sanitize the input through the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little update to excellent `David Gil del Rosal`'s answer which provides perfect solution for originally stated problem.

Since I am not a `Perl` guy I run into number of problems while trying to implement explained in answer solution.

Here is list of thing I did to make it work.

My setup `Ubuntu 16.04`,`Apache 2.4.18` and  `Perl 5.22`

1. Install `libapache2-mod-perl2`
2. Create file to host custom handler

Apache2 mod_perl module (`libapache2-mod-perl2`) expects to find custom code in one of the following locations

```
/etc/perl 
/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22.1 
/usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.22 
/usr/share/perl5 
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.22 
/usr/share/perl/5.22 
/usr/local/lib/site_perl 
/etc/apache2
```

I chose `/etc/perl`, that might not be the best location but that is what I used.

Used in example package `MyApache2::ConvertUsrToLowercase` and my chosen location translated into `/etc/perl/MyApache2/ConvertUsrToLowercase.pm` file

3. Handler configuration

In my case it was `/etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.conf`

```
<Location /xyz>
   DAV svn
   ...
   AuthzForceUsernameCase Lower
   PerlHeaderParserHandler MyApache2::ConvertUsrToLowercase
   ...
</Location>
```

4. Changes to handler code

Due some compilation errors had to add couple packages

```
use APR::Table;
use Apache2::Access;
```

Final code

```
# /etc/perl/MyApache2/ConvertUsrToLowercase.pm
package MyApache2::ConvertUsrToLowercase;

use strict;
use APR::Base64;
use APR::Table;
use Apache2::RequestRec;
use Apache2::Access;
use Apache2::Const -compile => qw(OK DECLINED);

sub handler {
    my $request = shift;
    my $header = "Authorization";
        my ($res, $passwd) = $request->get_basic_auth_pw;        # get passwd
        my $user = lc $request->user;                            # get lowercase login
        my $auth_header = APR::Base64::encode("$user:$passwd");
        # rewrite header & return OK
        $request->headers_in->{'Authorization'} = "Basic $auth_header";
    return Apache2::Const::OK;
}

1;
```

5. All troubleshooting was done by looking at apache2 error log file `/var/log/apache2/error.log`